# Core-Plot: Trouble Displaying Graph

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I've just added the Core-Plot library to my XCode (iOS) project.  The project now compiles fine.  However, after looking in the sample code included, as well as browsing online resources, I can't figure out how to just add a simple graph.

I was hoping someone could please give me a brief step-by-step of how to start off with a very basic graph.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples that come with core-plot? There's several of them that show simple plots, even if they're actually doing multiple plots in one view.  There no such thing as a five line app that will do a plot.  It takes about 20 lines minimum to lay out a simple one.

Comment: There's not much in the XIB file. There's just the one CPTView object (I forget the exact name), and one outlet connecting to it from the controller object.  You should be able to find those in the examples.